# How do I solve this Javascript memory management error?

Tags: javascript, html, garbage-collection

I have a picture array that is stored globally. Every second I choose a picture on the screen, fade it out, and replace it with a picture from the array. I use: `$("#picture" + picture.id).remove()` to remove the current picture from the screen. Then I use

```
$(".pictureframe").prepend(

<div id="picture+picture.id" class="imageframe" style="opacity:0; left:x px; top:y px;" >
    <img class="image" width="picture.width" height="picture.height" src="picture.source" />
</div>

);
```

I removed all the escaping to make it easier to read. picture is the object so picture.id is the pictures id. The problem is that having the page open (and the only one open) kills browser memory. I get to 1.4gb usage with just that page. I imagine that the browser is creating a clone of the image every time it gets reinserted. Is there a garbage collector delete function I can call on the DOM elements I removed? How would I do that?

Comment: you are deleting then from DOM, but are asking for help on removing from DOM. have you actually checked that they are deleted from DOM?

Comment: yea, firebug shows that there are only 10 elements in the picture frame (which is correct).

Comment: Please post actual code. What you posted isn't valid JavaScript and won't run. If you need help with a memory leak, you need to post the code that is causing the leak.

Comment: The code is way too long to post in a question, also the question is simple enough to understand what I meant without seeing all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about doing it is to have all the images there at once, but with all-but-one of them set to `display: none`, then fade them in/out as needed. This way there's no real DOM manipulation, only styles, and memory won't leak out of your computer's USB ports :p